# Verilog test bench incorrectly reading test vector

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to use a test bench to simulate a 4-input XOR function. I've specified the test inputs and expected outputs in a test vector file. This isn't homework, just for personal interest. For the first 8 (0000 through 0111) inputs, the expected output is being misread from the test vector. The final 8 are okay.

I used the test bench to verify a different combinational circuit, and it worked fine. I modified slightly to simulate my XOR function, and now it is not working as expected.

Any help, comments, suggestions, etc. are appreciated!

XOR module:

```
module xor_4(input [3:0] a, 
                output y);

assign y = ^a;

endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module testbench3();
reg clk, reset;
reg a, b, c, d, yexpected;
wire y;
reg [31:0] vectornum, errors;
reg [3:0] testvectors [10000:0];

// instantiate device under test
xor_4 dut({a, b, c, d}, y);

// generate clock
always
    begin
        clk = 1; #5; clk = 0; #5;
    end

// at start of test, load vectors
// and pulse reset
initial
    begin
        $readmemb("xor_4.tv", testvectors);
        vectornum = 0; errors = 0;
        reset = 1; #27; reset = 0;
    end

// apply test vectors at rising edge of clock
always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        #1; {a, b, c, d, yexpected} = 
              testvectors[vectornum];

    end

// check results at falling edge of clock
always @ (negedge clk)
    if (~reset) begin
        if (y !== yexpected) begin
            $display ("Error: inputs = %b", {a, b, c, d});
            $display (" outputs = %b (%b expected)", y, yexpected);
            errors = errors + 1;
        end
        //$display (" %b %b %b %b %b ", a, b, c, d, yexpected);
        vectornum = vectornum + 1;
        if (testvectors[vectornum] === 4'bx) begin
            $display ("%d tests completed with %d errors", vectornum, errors);

            $finish;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Test vector:

```
0000_0
0001_1
0010_1
0011_0
0100_1
0101_0
0110_0
0111_1
1000_1
1001_0
1010_0
1011_1
1100_0
1101_1
1110_1
1111_0
```

Output from iverilog script:

```
C:\iverilog>iverilog -o test testbench3.v xor_4.v
C:\iverilog>vvp test
 WARNING: testbench3.v:17: $readmemb: Standard inconsistency, following 1364-200
.
 WARNING: testbench3.v:17: $readmemb(xor_4.tv): Not enough words in the file for
the requested range [0:10000].
Error: inputs = 0000
  outputs = 0 (1 expected)
Error: inputs = 0001
 outputs = 1 (0 expected)
Error: inputs = 0010
 outputs = 1 (0 expected)
Error: inputs = 0011
 outputs = 0 (1 expected)
Error: inputs = 0100
 outputs = 1 (0 expected)
Error: inputs = 0101
 outputs = 0 (1 expected)
Error: inputs = 0110
 outputs = 0 (1 expected)
Error: inputs = 0111
 outputs = 1 (0 expected)
        16 tests completed with          8 errors
```

Comment: The first stage is obvious : after reading in the vectors, print them right out. My guess is they will print out wrong, and you're not reading the vector file you think you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the warning messages at the beginning of the simulation:

> WARNING: testbench3.v:17: $readmemb: Standard inconsistency, following 1364-200 .
>   WARNING: testbench3.v:17: $readmemb(xor_4.tv): Not enough words in the file for the requested range [0:10000].

Each entry of `testvector` is 4 bits wide, however `xor_4.tv` is 5 bits and `{a,b,c,d,yexpected}` is also 5 bits.

Change `reg [3:0] testvector [10000:0];` to `reg [4:0] testvector [0:10000];`

Comment: Lovely, that fixed it. Also had to change

    if (testvectors[vectornum] === 4'bx)
to

    if (testvectors[vectornum] === 5'bx), otherwise it won't display the total number of test errors.